# How to call a web service method from jquery in pure html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

I want to call a web service function from an html with jquery but it returns an error like this :

```
Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027to\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)...
```

My html page on `www.xxxxx.com/website/demo.html` and web service runs on `www.xxxxx.com/web/xx.asmx`

Here is my js:

```
 <script>
        function mail() {


            var email = 'xxxx';
            var nameSurname = 'xxxx';
            var phone = 'xxx';
            var siteName = 'asdf';
            var numberOfApartment = '3';
            var mission = 'asdf';

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://www.xxxxx.com/web/xx.asmx/SendMail',
                data: JSON.stringify({ to: email, nameSurname: nameSurname, phone: phone, siteName: siteName, numberOfApartment: numberOfApartment, mission: mission }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Successed");
                },
                error:
                    function (result) {
                        alert('error');

                    }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And here is my web service function:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string SendMail(string to, string nameSurname, string phone, string siteName, string numberOfApartment, string mission)
    {

       return "";
    }
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: `ata:` should be `data:` in your ajax config ;)

Comment: data mispelled ito ata .

Comment: I edit my question. Still the same result I have.

Comment: Try removing the `JSON.stringify()` around your object so just `data:{ to: email, ....}`

Comment: @DelightedD0D  if you want I can delete mine

Comment: @DelightedD0D, that time I have another error like : Invalid JSON primitive:xxx ...

Comment: change your content type to `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @cagin yeah, `JSON.stringify()` is actually correct for calling a service like yours, disregard that

Comment: @aliyouhannaei, still same error